# react hooks useEffect se ejecuta después de un componente

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, useeffect

**Soy nuevo en React.** Intento consultar la pokeapi usando  useEffect, la idea es que el estado "draw" cambie a true o false según si el componente resultPk ha cambiado, si es true quiero que se ejecute el componente Card y si es false que no se ejecute. Pero hay un problema cuando el estado anterior de "draw" es true y resultPk ha cambiado, useEffect no se ejecuta primero, use Effect se ejecuta después del Card

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Card from '../../components/Cards/Cards'
import axios from 'axios';

const Search =() =>{
    const [nombrePk,setPokemon] = useState('')
    const [resultPk,setResulPk] = useState({});
    const [draw,setDraw] = useState(false);

    const handleChangeNamePk = (event)=>{
        setPokemon(event.target.value)
    }
    
    const handleSubmit = async (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    const handleApiPk = async () => {
  
        try{
            let result = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${nombrePk}`)
            console.log('resul',result)
            if(result.data){setResulPk(result.data)
            console.log('resul',result)}else{setResulPk({}) }
        }catch(e){
            console.error(e) 
            setResulPk({})
        }
        
    }
    useEffect (()=>{
        console.log('--- ejecuto useEffect ---')
        if(resultPk.hasOwnProperty('name'))setDraw(true)
        else setDraw(false)
    },[resultPk])

    
        return(
            <div className='formPokemon'>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <label>Pokemon : </label>
                    <input type='text' name='namepokemon' onChange={handleChangeNamePk}/>
                    <button type='submit' onClick={handleApiPk}>buscar</button>
                </form>
                {draw===true?<Card infoPk={resultPk} />:''}
            </div>
        );
    
}
export default Search;
```

Este es el código del componente Card

```
import React from 'react';
import './Cards.css'
const Card = (props) =>{
    /* console.log(props.infoPk) */
    console.log('** ejecuto componente cards**')
    return(
        <div className="box">
            <p>{props.infoPk.name}</p>  
            <img src={props.infoPk.sprites.front_default} alt='pokemon'/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Card;
```

Cuando se ejecuta primero el componente Card antes que el useEffect falla la ejecución porque Card no es capaza de encontrar los datos a mostrar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mostrar que se ejecuta primero Card y luego useEffect voy a controlar la falta de datos en el controlador Card. He añadido un "?" en `<img src={props.infoPk.sprites?.front_default} alt='pokemon'/>`

```
import React from 'react';
import './Cards.css'
const Card = (props) =>{
    /* console.log(props.infoPk) */
    console.log('** ejecuto componente cards**')
    return(
        <div className="box">
            <p>{props.infoPk.name}</p>  
            <img src={props.infoPk.sprites?.front_default} alt='pokemon'/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Card;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como indico arriba soy nuevo en React si alguien me puede echar una mano con este problema estaría agradecido.

Un saludo

Gracias

Comment: que es lo que contiene `result.data`?

Comment: result.data es el resultado que te devuelve la API, es un objecto JSON

Answer (score 0):

Ya está solucionado el problema era de lógica, en el ejemplo que puse no hay que controlar el estado del array, hay que controlar el estado del input text que es el que va variando